# Verizon Droid X - phone won't vibrate

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-droid-x, vibration

I've got a Droid X that's been operating fine since a did a hard reset on it a couple weeks ago. Recently however the vibration function has completely ceased. I can't seem to find a setting to set the "strength" of the feedback- is there such a setting? The phone is running Gingerbread (2.3.3) build 4.5.602.

Answer (score 2):

On my Galaxy S, the vibration settings are under `Settings -> Sound`.  The **Vibrate** option has 4 choices (Always, Never, Only in silent mode, and Only when not in silent mode) and when the **Haptic feedback** option is checked, **Vibration intensity** can be set to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 but I don't think that affects regular vibrations.